# D6 + Services 3 + Appcelerator = Login help!

Tags: 6, services

I am in the process of (slowly) converting a community forum site from vb4 to drupal. Before I can make the full switch I need to put together a mobile app similar to tapatalk as a large number of my users post almost strictly from their phones.

I had done a little work previously with Services 2 but only on one project that didn't end up coming to fruition.

I am using D6 and Services 3 on this project and I am having trouble figuring out how to login.

I have set my endpoint to 'api/user' for all user resources. That means my login url would be 'api/user/user/login', correct? Using Poster on Chrome I get a "406 Not Acceptable: Unsupported request content type application/xml" when I try to pass along POST data.

Are there any tutorials or docs out there that I am missing? Any clues on what I might be doing wrong? I am finding it extremely difficult to find much out there for Services 3.

Answer (score 0):

make your endpoint 'api'

THen your login url is, 'api/user/login' POST

And also check to make sure you have allowed application/xml as a value response format at admin/structure/services/list/api/server

Although you might need to wait for this patch to be committed 
http://drupal.org/node/1232984

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've got it posting and returning 200 OK. I'm not quite sure where to go from here, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Request parsing  under SERVER tab. Make sure

multipart/form-data & application/x-www-form-urlencoded is checked

[image]